Swift BLE list peripherals always showing error
I am writing swift for iOS to list all the available BLE devices but every time I get the following error "[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid"
Steps followed:

in info.plist added the bluetooth permissions
My BLE device is already on and working from other apps

Here is my code
class BluetoothManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        //centralManager
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            scanForPeripherals()
        } else {
            print("Bluetooth not available.")
        }
    }

    func scanForPeripherals() {
        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        print("Scanning for peripherals...")
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("Discovered peripheral: \(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown")")
    }
}



class ViewController: UIViewController
{
   
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           let bm = BluetoothManager()
           
           
       }
}


As soon as viewDidLoad returns your Bluetooth manager will be released. Use an instance property, not a local variable.

It solved the issue with proper initialization
